# Ember 2: How to add custom jQuery

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Where does the following go?

```
$('a').click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top
    }, 500);
    return false;
});
```

I'm also working in the Rails environment then Ember frontend inside the Rails app. I tried it in the Ember vendor's folder and called the import in ember-cli-build.js, and when I go to test it, nothing works. Am I missing a step?

Comment: <a {{action 'blah'}}> ...

Answer (score 0):

When you add something with `app.import` on `ember-cli-build.js` that will make that code a part of your `vendor.js` file. The vendor.js file is downloaded and executed (to my knowledge) before the application is available. Meaning that your templates are not rendered by the time your code is executed, and your `$('a')` will return an empty list (hence why it's not working).

If you want to do exactly that I believe you may need to do event delegation, something like this:

```
$( "body" ).on( "click", "a", function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top
}, 500);
return false;
});
```

So that you delegate your click events to `a` links when they are already available in the app.

The ember way of running code like this (jquery code) would probably be to create a component, but I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve with this code.

Comment: Only on my homepage, when I click on a navigation link, I just want it to scroll to its designated anchor tag. I tried the code above and that still isn't working. When I put it directly in the console, the code does work. So my problem is that I can't find a way to call this after the page load. Through the component way, as I am completely new to Ember application, what exactly do I need in order to accomplish this? Please include example of file name and exactly what goes into this file.

Comment: Can you share more details about how that homepage/navigation link, looks like? Is it a component, template with {{link-to}}.